# Using a const key for unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl

I've been switching my code over from `std::map` to `std::unordered_map` where appropriate.  With `std::map`, I typically write the following just to make sure the key cannot be modified:

```
std::map<const std::string, int>
```

Frankly, I never checked if this `const` was of any value.  This has always compiled and worked with g++.

Now, with `std::unordered_map`, the following fails to link with g++ 4.5.1.

```
std::unordered_map<const std::string, std::string> m;
m["foo"] = "bar";
```

with this link error:

> Undefined symbols:
>   `"std::hash<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const>::operator()(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) const"`, referenced from:

The fix is simple, to remove `const`, but besides that, is there even a point in STL with any of the associative container classes to use a `const` key type?  Are there no methods that let you get a reference to the key for any associative container?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The associative containers only expose the (key,value) pair as `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`, so the additional const on the key type is superfluous.

Comment: Or in other words: `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>` will do what he wants. (Says Jonathan, restating the obvious-to-most.)

Comment: Heh, yes, I can see how my answer requires looking at the original question to understand it :)

Comment: This makes so much sense. The things I struggle with in the morning. Thanks @MSN

Comment: This answer tells the asker, he does not _need_ to do, what he was doing. The question, why he _cannot_ do it, remains...

Answer (score 1):

`std::unordered_map<std::string const, std::string>` uses `std::hash<std::string const>`, but no specialization exists for `hash<std::string const>`. However, there is one for `std::hash<std::string>`. You can provide one if you wish to use a `std::string const` as your key:

```
struct constant_string_hash {
    std::size_t operator () (std::string const &s) const {
        return hash<std::string>{}(s);
    }
};
```

You can then declare your `std::unordered_map` like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string const, std::string, constant_string_hash> m;
m["test key"] = "test value";
```