# C++ unordered_map causing compile-time error

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<tuple>

using namespace std;

class CTest {
    // Properties
    public:
        unordered_map<const string, tuple<int, int> > Layout;
    // Methods
    public:
        CTest ();
        ~CTest ();
};

CTest::CTest () {
    Layout["XYZ"] = make_tuple (0, 1);
}

CTest::~CTest () {
  // Do nothing
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CTest Test;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this simple programme gives the following error:

> error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to changing `Layout` to:

```
unordered_map<string, tuple<int, int> > Layout;
```

as stated by Johan and Benjamin you also need to `#include <string>`.

*Note, I do not understand why the change to `Layout` is required, even if the `const` is superfluous.*

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Sorry, I did indeed have #include<cstring> in my actual source code.  Unfortunately, I get the same error even after the removal of const.

Comment: @Shredderroy no, not `cstring` just `string`

Comment: Could you update the post with your exact code in case there is some other discrepancy? After I made these changes the code compiles for me in VS2010 (with extensions disabled).

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the const qualifier on the key.

```
unordered_map<const string, tuple<int, int> > Layout;
```

into

```
unordered_map<string, tuple<int, int> > Layout;
```

this is because keys are always const, according to this answer:

[Using a const key for unordered_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998978/using-a-const-key-for-unordered-map)

I figure the underlying reason is related to [Duplicate const qualifier allowed in C but not in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781222/duplicate-const-qualifier-allowed-in-c-but-not-in-c)

Also, as other posts pointed out you may need to include string (although with gcc it seems to come with iostream)

Comment: Thanks for the links.  As noted above, the compilation fails even with const removed, but I will read your links for further hints.

Comment: Shredderroy your code works and compiles fine with the const removed under gcc4.7 c++11.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out, the reason for your initial error was that you needed to include `<string>`.  However, you may have another problem with this:

```
unordered_map<const string, tuple<int, int> > Layout;
```

You (may) need to remove the const from that string:

```
unordered_map<string, tuple<int, int> > Layout;
```

This may not be necessary on your compiler, but it is on mine.  First of all, the const is superfluous, map/unordered_map keys are const anyway, but that is not the problem.  The problem has to do with the hash function template not working for const types.

The following simple program isolates the problem for me:

```
#include <functional>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::hash<const int> h;
    h(10);
}
```

http://ideone.com/k2vSy

```
undefined reference to `std::hash<int const>::operator()(int) const'
```

I cannot, at present time, explain this.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I cannot.  I don't think it has anything to do with the reason that it's unnecessary, because that reason also applies to `std::map`.  However, I get no compile error with `map<const string, tuple<int, int>>`.  I know it has something to do with the hash function, but I cannot explain it.

Comment: Ok, +1 and thanks for trying then. Edit: Yeah, I don't get any compile errors either. Weird.

Comment: Thanks the response.  The compilation still fails, even with const removed, but I am trying to use the discussions here to investigate further.

Comment: Benjamin, your response also contains the solution to my problem.  Seth's came first, so I accepted that.  But thank you very much.

Comment: I'm late to the party here, but only specific specializations of std::hash are provided by the library.  std::hash<string> is one of them, std::hash<const string> is not.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 will compile your source code as is as long as you `#include <string>` so that it has the comparison tests for `string` available.

As the other posters mention, you *should* also make your key a regular `string` rather than a `const string`, as this is conformant to the STL standard, but this is not strictly necessary to make VS 2010 compile the source above.

Comment: FYI, if you compile with extensions disabled compilation fails unless you make the change to `Layout`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  As noted aobve, the compilation fails even with const removed.