# Why does std::hash not work on const strings?

Tags: c++, hash, c++17

How comes that `std::hash` does not exist for `const std::string`?

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::hash<std::string> hasher1;       // works
    std::hash<const std::string> hasher2; // does not work
}
```

As expected, I can use the regular `std::string` specialization for example in a hash map:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<const std::string, int, std::hash<std::string>> a;
}
```

I feel like there is a better reason than "Well, they just didn't do it" to the const specialization missing. What is it?

Comment: Just a guess but an some point they had to stop the specialisations:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: Well, they just didn't do it.

Comment: Doesn't operator() of a hash struct take a const argument anyway? Try passing a const string to your second example. It will probably work, meaning that it would have been redundant to specialize for const.

Comment: Why do you have `unordered_map<const std::string, int>` instead of just `unordered_map<std::string, int>`?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's why the `unordered_map` in the second snippet works as well. I am just surprised that those specializations did not exist.

Comment: I was just going around `const`ing things. After some more reading, the const on the key does not seem to do anything anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998978/using-a-const-key-for-unordered-map