# How to copy unordered_map with a const key?

Tags: c++, stl

Simple code:

```
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<const int, int> m;
  std::unordered_map<const int, int> m1 = m;
}
```

produces convoluted compile error message:

> Error C2280   'std::hash<_Kty>::hash(void)': attempting to reference a
>   deleted function

which basically says `unordered_map` in its internals doesn't expect the key to be constant

**PS**:
I've read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999018/4440694) for the analogous question:

> The associative containers only expose the (key,value) pair as
>   std::pair, so the additional const on the
>   key type is superfluous.

But it doesn't explain why the hashmap with a const key is practically unusable and how to circumvent the issue

Comment: Unrelated: The key in a `unsorted_map` is `const` anyway. Think of how nasty it would be to keep the order right if any shmuck could change the key whenever they wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type

```
std::unordered_map<const int, int>
```

uses a defaulted third parameter `std::hash<const int>`. This hash type, unlike `std::hash<int>`, is not specialized by the standard library, and so is `deleted` (as the error message says).

A working hash is required when copying an unordered_set. To make a working hash:

1. You can specialize `std::hash<const int>` by yourself, so that it is no longer deleted:

   ```
   namespace std 
   { 
     // fixes it but is a bad idea - could break in future revisions of the standard
     template<>
     struct hash<const int> : hash<int>{};
   }
   ```
2. Or you can explicitly state your hash:

   ```
   std::unordered_map<const int, int, std::hash<int>>
   ```
3. Or you can get rid of the const in the key (as it has no effect):

   ```
   std::unordered_map<int, int>
   ```

**Addendum**:

**Deleted** means that the constructor of the non-specialized `std::hash` is deleted:

```
template <typename T>
struct hash
{
   hash() = delete;
   hash(const hash) = delete;
   // more deleted methods
};
```

By "deleted", it means that it does not exist (neither user-provided nor default).

You can see this at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), where they use the terminology of enabled/disabled:

> For every type Key for which neither the library nor the user provides an enabled specialization std::hash, that specialization exists and is disabled.

Since `std::hash<const int>` is not provided by the library, it is disabled unless it is provided by the user. Next, the text explains what *disabled* is:

> Disabled specializations do not satisfy Hash, [...] std::is_default_constructible_v, std::is_copy_constructible_v [...] are all false. In other words, they exist, but cannot be used.

So, these constructors must be unavailable (and deleting them is the best way to do it).