# What is the difference between std::unordered_map<std::string, int> and std::unordred_map<const std::string, int>?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

What is the difference between `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` and `std::unordred_map<const std::string, int>`?

I found that if I use `std::unordred_map<const std::string, int>`, it fails to compile.

```cpp
std::unordered_map<const std::string, int> m;
m.insert(std::make_pair("Foo", 1)); //error
m["Bar"] = 2; // also error
```

But `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` works fine.

I think `std::unordred_map<const std::string, int>` should be fine, because the key of `unordered_map` is always `const`. But it's not working. Why is that?

Comment: You don't mention what exact error you see. I assume maybe missing std::hash specialization mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55095225/4074081. It should work after `std::hash<const std::string>` is defined.

Comment: That's a good question, and I don't have a definite answer other than `std::unordered map` doesn't define a constructor for a key of `const std::string`. The error is `error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >) (const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’`. So while you are correct that once the string is hashed the key is effectively `const`, the hash function just doesn't seem to be defined for it.

Comment: @dewaffled Your comment is just answer to my question. But why doesn't standard library specialize hash<const std::string> or other const type ? Is there any good reason?

Comment: I will close this question and  create new question about has<const std::string> specialization.